# Default values for parameters when using SimpleJSAP in Java

Tags: java

This is one of my command line parameters:

```
 new FlaggedOption("nrMaxIterations", JSAP.INTEGER_PARSER, null, JSAP.NOT_REQUIRED, JSAP.NO_SHORTFLAG,    "nrMaxIterations", "Maximum pool iterations to run")
```

Even though I set it such that the parameter is not required, as you can see in the third value passed,
I still get error:

```
exception: com.martiansoftware.jsap.UnspecifiedParameterException: Parameter 'nrMaxIterations' has no associated value.
```

This should not happen, I set that the parameter is not required, but for whatever reason it acts as required.

Thanks